# using cookie for mysql query is it safe?

Tags: php, html, mysql, cookies

am working in a project and i need to store data in cookies and use that data on a mysql query but am not sure about the security things..
alright here is my code..

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user_phone_id'])){
   echo "";
   $user_phone = $_COOKIE['user_phone'];
   $user_phone_id = $_COOKIE['user_phone_id'];
   $user_phone_url = strtr($user_phone, " ", "-");
   echo "";
   echo "<div id='phonelist_1' class='phonelist'>       
      <a style='color:white;font:bold 15px arial,helvetica,sans-serif; ' href='$user_phone_url'>
         <img src='./phones/".$user_phone_id.".jpg' alt='$user_phone' title='$user_phone' width='100px' height='100px' />
      </a><br />
      <a style='color:white;font:bold 15px arial,helvetica,sans-serif; ' href='$user_phone_url' title='$user_phone'>
         $user_phone
      </a><br /><div class='mobilebg'>";
   require_once "./phonec.php";
   $sql = "select mobile_name, mobile_id, parent_id from mobiles where parent_id =" . 
      $user_phone_id . " ";
   $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
   while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
      $cid = $rs['mobile_id'];
      $cname = $rs['name_name'];
      echo " <a href='./$cid' style='width: 100%; text-decoration:none;'>
         <div class='mobilatcat'>
         <em style='float: right;'></em>
         <em style='padding-right: 20%;float: right;'>$cname</em> 
         <hr style='margin: 5px;' /></div></a>";
   }
   echo "</div></div> ";
}
```

Comment: Cookies are user-input. They're just as easy to tamper with, from any browsers cookie manager.

Comment: If you want to avoid the cumbersome escaping, have you considered a [contemporary database interface](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) which makes this redundant?

Comment: the probleme is here $sql = "select mobile_name, mobile_id, parent_id from mobiles where parent_id =" . 
      $user_phone_id . " ";

Comment: the cookie goes directly to a sql query

Comment: Stop using `mysql_` functions for a first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not safe. You shouldn't store any database query or query data explicitly in cookies.

Cookies are just user inputs like mario's said and it's very easy to tamper. Consider a server-side storage option (session?) for data such like this.

If you really want to store such that data in cookies, always [validate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation) and filter it before sending to database.

Comment: i really need cookies.. do you suggest to use `if(mysql_num_rows(` to validate cookie if it exist in the database, or use a sample text file to validate it with

Comment: Cookies are stored in client's browser, not in database. So, mysql_num_rows() is a just a database related method, you can't use that for data validation nor cookie existence. Use filter_var, is_number, is_string like methods or regular expression to validate cookie data.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use php Sessions

```
<?php
 session_start();
 // store session data
 $_SESSION['views']=1;
 ?>
```

Comment: cause i dont want to lose data when closing the browser

Answer (score -2):

Use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) object, which is widely supported across browsers (IE8+).

localStorage.setItem( 'someData', 42 );later (even when the website or browser was closed)

localStorage.getItem( 'someData' ) // === 42

Comment: its the same as cookies, stores the data in the localStorage rather in the browser.

Comment: I know what localStorage is. Please explain how does this help the OP with the security concerns.